# R subset vector when treated as strings

Tags: r, string, vector, subset

I have a large data frame where I've forced my vectors into a string (using lapply and toString) so they fit into a dataframe and now I can't check if one column is a subset of the other. Is there a simple way to do this.

```
X <- data.frame(y=c("ABC","A"), z=c("ABC","A,B,C"))

 X
      y     z
1   ABC   ABC
2    A   A,B,C


all(X$y %in% X$z)
[1] FALSE

(X$y[1] %in% X$z[1])
[1] TRUE

(X$y[2] %in% X$z[2])
[1] FALSE
```

I need to treat each y and z string value as a vector (comma separated) again and then check if y is a subset of z.

In the above case, A is a subset of A,B,C. However because I've treated both as strings, it doesnt work.

In the above y is just one value and z is 1 and 3. The data frames sample I'll be testing is 10,000 rows and the y will have 1-5 values per row and z 1-100 per row. It looks like the 1-5 are always a subset of z, but I'd like to check.

Comment: try using `apply(X, 1, function(x) x[1] %in% unlist(strsplit(x[2], ",")))`

Comment: You have only a single string in each row  It is not clear what you wanted `as.character(X[,1])==as.character(X[,2])` or may be `mapply(grepl, X$y, X$z)`

Comment: Try `grepl(X$y[2], X$z[2])` or `mapply(grepl, X$y, X$z)`

Comment: Actually you will need to define if you want perfect subset or not. for e.g. if `X$y[2] == "A,B,D"` then what you you expect as output?

Comment: Tried mapply but got: Error in (function (pattern, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE, fixed = FALSE,  : 
  invalid regular expression 'Embedded Software Programming,C++,Instrumentation,JavaScript,NI LabVIEW', reason 'Invalid use of repetition operators'

Comment: For example one value (equiv to X$y[1]) looks like: ASP.NET,VBscript,C#,VB6,C++

Comment: @Olivia maybe you should share the `dput` of your original (a sample of it anyway) data frame

Comment: @Sotos Probably adding fixed=TRUE would work (I suspect "++" caused the error), though without real data, can't say for sure.

Comment: @lmo yes makes sense. "Invalid regex" points towards it

Comment: It worked, but said everything was false.  Joe wilsons tech worked perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = data.frame(y=c("ABC","A"), z=c("ABC","A,B,C"))

apply(df, 1, function(x) {               # perform rowise ops.
  y = unlist(strsplit(x[1], ","))        # splitting X$y if incase it had ","  
  z = y %in% unlist(strsplit(x[2], ",")) # check how many of 'X$y' present in 'X$z'
  if (sum(z) == length(y))               # if all present then return TRUE
    return(TRUE)
  else
    return(FALSE)
})

# 1] TRUE TRUE

# Case 2: changed the data. You will have to define if you want perfect subset or not. Accordingly we can update the code
df = data.frame(y=c("ABC","A,B,D"), z=c("ABC","A,B,C"))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great. Looks like the only time it shows a false is when z ends in a comma which then puts a double comma in y.

Comment: It shows `FALSE` when all the elements of X$z are not there in X$y.

Comment: If you want `TRUE` even when a single element of X$y is present in X$z then replace the `return` with `return(ifelse(any(z), TRUE, FALSE))`

Answer (score 1):

I think it might work better for you not to use your `lapply` and `toString` combination, but store the lists in your data frame. For this purpose, I find the `tbl_df` (as found in the `tibble` package) more friendly, although I believe `data.table` objects can do this as well (someone correct me if I'm wrong)

```
library(tibble)

y_char <- list("ABC", "A")
z_char <- list("ABC", c("A", "B", "C"))

X <- data_frame(y = y_char, 
                z = z_char)
```

Notice that when you print `X` now, your entries in each row of the `tibble` are entries from the list.  Now we can use `mapply` to do  pairwise comparison.

```
# All y in z
mapply(function(x, y) all(x %in% y),
       X$y,
       X$z)


# All z in y
mapply(function(x, y) all(y %in% x),
       X$y,
       X$z)
```

Comment: If you saw the length of my code you'd agree im not rewriting it haha, I will certainly bear this in mind in the future though so thanks! One question, when you view the data frame, you see c("A", "B", "C"). So I guess it would be written to a csv like that too which may be problematic.

Comment: `write.csv` kicks an error out when I try to write it with the list format.  The error message is `unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'`. So you can't write it to a csv at all if you need to.  You would have to make a conscious decision of how you wanted to store it in a flat format.